# Changing xs:complexType in existing Webservice

Tags: xsd, wsdl

I have an existing Webservice with a complexType as a **return** value.

```
<xs:complexType name="dummy">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="A" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Later on (after a few clients are in Production) I want to extend my Webservice.
In Detail I want to add a new optional subelement of the complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="dummy">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="A" type="xs:string" /> 
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="B" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Am I breaking existing Clients? If yes, what is a correct/usual way to handle enhancements of existing Webservices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your question literary, the answer is **yes**.

Java clients are based on generated code, and they are validating if actual contract matches that from which the client is generated. I've broken contract for JAX-WS-generated Java client by adding new method - which theoretically should not be an issue. But I was setting endpoint address in initialization code.

Some clients that are not validating can work with changed contract as long as they do not meet unknown fields. In your case, as long as you optional new element won't show up, they will consume the message, but they will throw an error when such element will be existant in the message (our client has hmmm... well.. client, that was operating in such way, they've had old definition, but the new field was almost always null - and not present in XML).

Dynamically generated clients (such as in Python) are generating responses based on current contract, and because in that languages you can add new fields to existing objects, they will work without any problems in your case.

So the long answer is: **it depends** on what clients are using your contract.

How to manage such changes: it's not a nice way, but if you have no influence on what clients are used and when they are updated, leave the old web service and publish new version paralell under new URL.